# Converting API requests

Tags: api-design

OK. This is my first question on this illustrious site so forgive me if I've not researched etc.

I'm beginning to get my head round making API requests and I've also started to learn Python. I have a specific application that if I can work out how to do it, would make a huge difference to how I do things. I want to create a "middleman" to change the JSON structure of an API request.

I would have System A making a GET request to populate a data list. This system needs the response that looks like this…

```
  "DataSources":[
      {
         "Id":"parties",
         "Rows":[
            [
               "11587",
               "null",
               "null",
               "Scott",
               "Spacey",
               "Creative Director"
```

And System B responds with something that looks something like this…

```
   {
  "parties": [
    {
      "id": 11587,
      "about": null,
      "title": null,
      "firstName": "Scott",
      "lastName": "Spacey",
      "jobTitle": "Creative Director"
```

So, is there a practical way to create something that receives the GET requests from System A, converts it, and manipulates the response from System B in a new JSON structure that SYSTEM A can handle…

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. The below converts the API get request results from json to a python list of dictionaries. There might be a more elegant way, but this works for now.  Hope this helps.

```
import requests, json

response = requests.get(strEndPointUrl)

## convert json to string and then string to Python list
strOutput = json.dumps(response.json())
ListOutPut = json.loads(strOutput)

for dictOutPut in ListOutPut:
     print(['Key1'])
```